# Photons can be regarded as particles?

Tags: energy, photons, matter

So I've been reading an article and stopped at this sentence :
"Likewise, we can take energy (such as particles of light, called photons) and turn it into matter."
He gave an example of energy which is particle of light... But I know that particles are regarded as matter, and photons are a pack of energy, is it right to call them particles? I'm confused

Comment: Can you send a link to the article?

Comment: http://www.emc2-explained.info/Emc2/Basics.htm#.VsWK-1nRZzT. Section :"what does the equation mean?"

Comment: Photons are quanta of the electromagnetic field. Quanta are not particles and behave fundamentally differently. Particle in physics refers to a (classical) object that can be described by its center of mass coordinates, alone. Photons can not be described by center of mass coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title: yes, light is composed of photons which are classified as particles.

Your confusion arises from the word 'matter'. Matter is an ill-defined concept with no fundamental significance in physics. Nevertheless, it is common to use the term 'matter' to mean something with a rest mass. This seems to be the definition employed in the article you link: photons do not have a rest mass, but they can generate particles that *do* have rest mass.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the article is simply very misleading and somewhat incorrect. Mass and energy can be viewed as interchangeable which is expressed appropriately on the website but the case of the photon is a bit more complex because it is considered to be massless. The one property that it does have is energy and I think that is what the article refers to. This energy can lead to pair production but only in the vicinity of a massive particle such as an atomic nucleus for mass to be conserved.

Nonetheless the photon is considered to be a particle that has an associated spin.

Comment: Pair production does not necessarily require a massive particle: it can happen in photon-photon collisions (http://www-spires.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-pub-11581.pdf and references there).

Comment: So the photon is a particle with an associated spin, and a pack of energy at the same time?

Comment: @Za Kh Yes, it has.